# Rect.intersect doesn't work?

Tags: android

So I have an ImageView which moves to the top of the Activity using ObjectAnimator. I have these fields within the Activity:

```
Rect rocketRectangle, planet1Rectangle, planet2Rectangle, planet3Rectangle;
```

Within the onCreate method I set rocketRectangle by:

```
rocketRectangle = new Rect();
rocketImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_img);
rocketImageView.getDrawingRect(rocketRectangle);
```

I also have another method which creates LinearLayout's dynamically and within there I set the planet rectangle's within the for loop according to the index of the for loop, so:

```
if(i == 1)
{
   planet1Rectangle = new Rect();
   linearLayouts.get(i).getDrawingRect(planet1Rectangle);
}
```

Now within my onSensorChange method (which basically gets called every second) I have IF statements to check for collisions with any of the 3 rectangles (planet1Rectangle, planet2Rectangle and planet3Rectangle), so:

```
 Log.d("test", "we're running");
 if(rocketRectangle.intersect(planet1Rectangle))
 {
    Log.d("intersect", "planet1");
 }
```

Notice outside the IF statement I have a Log, this gets called soo many times however the Logs within the intersect if statement don't.. bare in mind the rocketImageView is also moving in the background whilst all of this is happening..

Does anyone know why non of the IF statements are returning true?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you set the correct filter on android monitor? The filter must either be set to **no filter** to see every log or you have to set **intersect** to see that special log. You said you see the Log before the if statement, here the keyword is **test** .....I guess you should set the same keywords to be sure all logs are displayed...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs My Android Monitor displays all logs.. Weirdly, rocketRectangle.top constantly returns 0, why could this be?